# Using a custom enumeration is aligned differently than a default enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[a.]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{enumerate}

\end{docment}
```

The output then shows those two lists where the 1st list is slightly indented and the 2nd list seems to be aligned with the textbody. How could I achieve that the custom enumerate behaves as the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't happen with `enumitem`. It is better to use `enumitem` instead of `enumerate` as the former is more flexible and modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```